# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "author_id" of relation "movie_movie" violates not-null constraint no idea why is this occurring

Tags: django

Seems like model is only getting "null". I tried to print the request user in views and it was fine.

View codes.

```
def add_item(request):  # add new media
quote = random.choice(quotes)
if request.method == "POST":
    new_item = MovieForm(request.POST)
    new_item.save(commit=False)
    new_item.author = request.user
    new_item.save()
    return redirect('movie:movie_library')
else:
    movie_form = MovieForm()
return render(request, 'movie/add_movie.html',
              context={'form': movie_form,
                       'quote': quote})
```

model

```
class Movie(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('Movie', 'Movie'),
    ('Tv-series', 'Tv Series'),
    ('Anime', 'Anime'),
)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
type = models.CharField(max_length=15,
                        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                        default='')
year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
rating = models.FloatField(max_length=10, null=False)
review = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
img_url = models.TextField(default='https://betravingknows.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/'
                                   '06/video-movie-placeholder-image-grey.png')
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

forms

```
from django import forms
from movie.models import Movie


class MovieForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title', 'type', 'year', 'review',
                  'rating', 'img_url', 'active')
```

error

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "author_id" of relation "movie_movie" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (46, Sapiens, Movie, 435, 6.5, ftght, https://betravingknows.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/video-movi..., t, null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, in your code you're not assigning the `request.user` to your new object, but to your form, thus it's not saving.

`form.save()` returns the new object and that's what you need to manipulate here.

Also, consider handling the case where the form is not valid with `form.is_valid()`.

```py
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MovieForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_item = form.save(commit=False)
        new_item.author = request.user
        new_item.save()
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `request.user` return `AnonymousUser` instead of registered one? In this case `author` will get `None` that will raise your error.
You can add [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator to your view in order to avoid this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def add_item(request):
    ...
```

Comment: @login_required is already there and the same error showing. Without login_required anonymoususer error message showing. " (46, Sapiens, Movie, 435, 6.5, ftght, https://betravingknows.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/video-movi..., t, null)." the last 'null' here is coming for the user.

Comment: Can you edit your topic to reflect actual code for view and form you are using? Also is same error raised with decorator?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. If you are using Django rest framework, and you have your serializer set up as follows:
`author` is foreign key. If you `POST` request is attempting to create a db object of model with a foreign key, then make sure it is not mentioned as read-only.

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')  # just comment this
    # author = UserSerializer(read_only=True) # remove this also if present

    ...
```

Please remove the readonly part. This stops the expected result to occur. Also make sure that, the `author` field receives the `id` of the type of foreingKey (here `User`).